# Default Homepage Overridden by Manufacturer Defaults

Tags: windows-7, script, windows-registry

I've got a Lenovo Thinkpad that I'm trying to change the default homepage in IE in for all users. I've tried a number of things, but every time I create a new user the homepage is always the Lenovo default homepages.

I've tried changing `Default_Page_URL` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` to the default I want, such as `www.google.com` for example, but the value is always reset to the Lenovo default when I create a new user.

Does this look like the work of a script that runs at the first login or am I editing the wrong value?

Comment: Lenovo might be using a custom default user profile.

Comment: Load the NTUSER.DAT hive of the "Default" user profile, and update the registry settings, and unload the hive. The settings should apply for every new user you create. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chad/2012/04/25/tip-49-how-do-you-set-default-user-profile-registry-settings/

Answer (score 0):

Start Regedit.exe and select the HKEY_USERS branch.
From the File menu, click Load Hive...
Select the following file:

> C:\users\default\ntuser.dat

Assign a Name for the loaded hive (eg. `defaultuser`)

Browse to the `Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main` branch of the loaded hive, and make the modifications as required.

Select the `defaultuser` hive. From the File menu, click `Unload hive...`

Exit Regedit.exe

Every new user profile you create will use the modified settings.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was looking for; unfortunately, the NTUSER.DAT file I have is funky in some way. It is only 1KB in size, and the properties suggest that it's actually a log file, not the actual data file. Is there anywhere else this file might be located? Perhaps there's an OEM folder hidden somewhere? Attempting to load this file results in a generic error and failure to load the hive.

Comment: The file is super-hidden. Simply type the file name with full path in the Load hive dialog box and click Open.